# ASP.NET MVC3 Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I've recently been looking into the areas functionality for my application and had partial success transferring code into my first area.

My question involves linking from inside an area to a location that **isn't** in an area. I've read the tutorial on how to link from one area to another, but while I still have code that isn't within an area how do I link to it?

> ```
> <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home", new )">
>      <span>Testing Link </span>
> </a>
> ```

How do I make this code, which currently links to /myarea/home/index instead link to /home/index (not in an area). If this is against best practices I'd be interesting in reading about it, I'm still learning ASP.NET's version of Areas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RouteValues` collection can take an area parameter. Just make it blank.

`new { area = "" }`

Comment: Simple quick answer, sad I didn't think of this myself, appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

link to an area:

```
@Url.Action("Index","Home", new { area = "YourAreaName" } )
```

link to a place out of any area:

```
@Url.Action("Index","Home", new { area = "" } )
```

**A helpful list:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ActionName", new { area = "AreaName" })
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ActionName", new { area = "" })

@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "AreaName" }, new { /* html attributes */ })
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "" }, new { /* html attributes */ })

<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", new { area = "AreaName" })">Link Text</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", new { area = "" })">Link Text</a>

<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "AreaName" })">Link Text</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { area = "" })">Link Text</a>
```